# Why claim types are converted in AddJwtBearer method in .net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

When adding JwtBearer authentication in a dotnet api application, the config option `MapInboundClaims` is set to true by default. This would convert some claim type names (see https://mderriey.com/2019/06/23/where-are-my-jwt-claims/)

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.MapInboundClaims = false // true by default.
        ...
    });
```

Would it be a little confusing to convert the claim types automatically behind the scene? What are the benefits of using these converted Microsoft claim types? Would it bring more values if converting these claim types rather than not doing that?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that Microsoft has a different opinion of what the name of the claims should be when it looks for the name and role. They are defined in the .NET source code [here](https://source.dot.net/#System.Security.Claims/System/Security/Claims/ClaimTypes.cs,1f8b9c14a9b34152) .

If you don't want this, we need to set the name of the name/role claim to match what the claims are named inside the token. You can use alternative names. In the authority add claims (instead of roles) in order to set the claim type. Where claim type for role could be 'role'.For example, the claims are named name and role.

In order to map the claim, configure the resource:

```
.AddJwtBearer(opt =>
{
    // ...
    opt.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "role";
    opt.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
    // ...
});
```

Note, the 'problem' remains that a JWT a public token is. The only way to really hide this kind of information is to not put it in the token and choose for a different design.

If Identity isn't adding the claims automatically for you then you may have to add some code, e.g. implement the IUserClaimStore. Also make sure the claim type is included when creating the token. The claims may be filtered or simply ignored, but that depends on the design.